# New computers can't connect to the network

Tags: networking, cisco, arp

Good Morning,

We have a business environment in which we have 3 Cisco 3850 PoE stacked and We manage our DHCP through our DC server.

Last weekend our UPS had a failure and switched off all outputs, so all the equipment has been reset since then.

On Monday I started noticing that first, I lost ping to a card reader that had been working fine until now. And sencond and most important: every new computer we plug into our network resolves DHCP fine but has no ping to our GW.

So here's what I know:

- DHCP requests go through just fine, I can see the new computer's records in our DHCP server.
- Ping works fine to other computers in the same Vlan/subnet, but I get 0 response from the Gateway
- With wireshark I could see that these computers spam ARP packets asking for our Gateway with 0 response
- I flushed my own ARP cache and I actually got a response from the ARP request first try
- If I use an USB network card from another computer that was already working, it works no problem, until today for some reason
- The MAC table in the switch has been flushed already
- Wi-Fi works OK, we have it on a different Vlan but similar setup with the same DHCP server.

Any ideas? I googled the hell out of it and I found no one with the same issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the DHCP scope handing out the address for the Gateway to new machines?

Comment: Yes it is. Its giving the correct address.

Comment: Is inter-vlan routing working?

Comment: Yes, we wouldn't have DHCP or  File Services otherwise

Comment: Aside from the card reader, are computers other than the new computers affected?

Comment: Nope, only things that hasn't been on the network in some time

Comment: Are they all in the same vlan, or are multiple vlans involved?

Comment: For now it looks like there's only one vlan affected, except for the card reader that could be unrelated.

Comment: So it sounds like it's either not responding to unknown/unfamiliar MAC addresses, or that VLAN.

Comment: It may be that changes were made on the router and never saved. If the router is not responding, you should edit your question to include the router configuration.

Comment: Side note: that's why you connect one PSU of the switches and machines to the UPS and the second directly to the power grid.

Answer (score 0):

We had what sounds like the same issue. Drove us crazy for 3 months. Turned out it was some sort of fast networking setting in the bios

Comment: Any update on the situation?

Comment: Sadly, no. For all I can say it stopped on it's own, but priorities shifted after a short while and we never looked at the issue again. Turns out the switches lost a small change on the power cycle, but that only solved the card reader problem that ended up being a wrong Vlan.